# printing values in hashtable Java

Tags: java, hashtable

My code stores values in a hashtable and I was wondering how can I print the `data` from the hashtable? I'm not quite sure how I can iterate through the hashtable to print out it's value. I'm quite new to Java so I don't really know which built in functions I can use.

My code:

```
public static void deleteDups(LinkedListNode n) {
    Hashtable table = new Hashtable();
    LinkedListNode previous = null;
    while (n != null) {
        if (table.containsKey(n.data)) {
            previous.next = n.next;
        }
        else {
            table.put(n.data, true);
            previous = n;
        }
        n = n.next;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(Object o : table.keySet()) {
    LinkedListNode lln = (LinkedListNode)o;
    System.out.println(lln.data);
}
```

Also note that you'd be better declaring your table as a `Hashtable<LinkedListNode, Boolean>`, which would allow you to iterate on the keys as

```
for(LinkedListNode lln : table.keySet()) {
    System.out.println(lln.data);
}
```

Comment: Also, you should probably be using HashMap instead of HashTable.